# Copying a datagridview image column as part of a table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, clipboard

I have a data grid view which is bound to a list of classes.
The data grid view includes an image column (`DataGridViewImageColumn`) which is bound to a `Byte()` datatype in the class.

[image: Image Column Screenshot]

I am copying data from the DataGridView to several other places (MS Excel/Outlook/Plain Text) however when I do the image column is obviously blank.

I can just copy the image data to the clipboard manually for a single image but is there any way I can include this image column in the data table copied to the clipboard?

Alternatively is there a way I can manually construct the clipboard data to include the images?

I've had a look through the clipboard formats listed 
[on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I can't see one that could include all this information.

If it helps, the simplified class definition:

```vb
Public Class Booking

    Public Property bookingID As Integer
    ...
    Public Property identString As String
    Public Property image As Byte() ' <--- My Image Column
    Public Property complete As Boolean
    ...
    Public Property bookedInDate As DateTime?
    Public Property bookedOutDate As DateTime?

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own clipboard format (either private or registered) and use a data handle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Private_Clipboard_Formats

Depending on your application, it might be easier to use some kind of indirection, such as a pointer(s) in the clipboard to the images.